# How to use QTimer for non-ui task in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, timer

In my QT project I want to do a non ui activity; which is sending files to server every 60 minutes.

I tried using QTimer for it and for that QCoreApplication instance is also needed.

The timer does start and call the upload function periodically but it keeps QCoreApplication hostage (unable to delete it as timer would be running infinitely)  and ultimately application crashes.

I tried to move QTimer to another thread, but that also doesn't solve the issue as app is still running in main thread.

Below is code of function which is called from __stdcall function loaded during dll initialization.

```
{
    int argc=0;
    QCoreApplication app(argc, nullptr);
    QThread* newThread = new QThread(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(0);
    timer->setInterval(60*60*1000);
    timer->moveToThread(newThread);
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(uploadFiles()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    timer->connect(newThread, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(start()));
    newThread->start();
    app.exec();
}
```

Maybe this is not best approach to do it . Need guidance on how to achieve it.

**Update**:
Figured out that Qtimer is definitely not ideal way to achieve it.
I was able to perform periodic execution using std::thread and atomic.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the `QCoreApplication`?  Qt expects that the application object will remain present for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: The timer will only run as long as your application runs. No need for threads, here. If you don't want to keep your application running, use a different approach such as cron jobs in *nix.

Comment: Offtopic: since Qt5, member function pointers are supported in connections. So `SIGNAL(timeout())` would become `&QTimer::timeout`. Likewise for the `SLOT` macros. This will enable the compiler to check your connections (among other things) and should generally be preferred.

Comment: And one last thing, the `QTimer` does not keep the `QApplication` "hostage". It's the other way around. The `QApplication` runs the main event loop which records how much time elapsed so the timer can work at all. The application keeps the timer _alive_.

Comment: @Freidrich The function containing above code is called from __stdcall init_function having return type int. After its execution the control is never back in caller function. I don't see any logs in caller function after the above function call hence my assumption is QApplication or QTimer is running indefinitely causing system hang and crash. And if I manually delete QApplication app then application doesn't crash and obviously timer also doesn't work